# How to show desktop icons and have hovering view of keybindings in Gnome 3.14?

Tags: debian, gnome, window-manager, super-key

Fig. 1 Ubuntu's help of common keybindings which I would like to find too in Debian, Fig. 2 Searching *desktop* in *super*-view of Debian

[image]
    [image]

I am thinking if there is any hovering cheat sheet in Debian, see Fig. 1 for the corresponding feature in Ubuntu under two times of <kbd>super</kbd>. 
I am struggling to find features in Debian such as

- show  only Desktop - in Ubuntu <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> but cannot find it in keybindings, not in any icons and not in Debian's search of Fig. 2
- ...

OS: Debian 8.5
Window manager: Gnome 3.14

Comment: That's a window-manager specific feature (and almost all of Ubuntu *comes* from Debian without noticeable improvement).  Likely it exists in Debian, but was part of  *testing* rather than *stable*.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Yes, you are right. There should be something corresponding. I am trying to understand how Debianists think.

Comment: Actually in this case the software involved doesn't come from Debian. Ubuntu's desktop environment and window manager, Unity, is Ubuntu-specific; that's what provides the help screen. I don't know of an equivalent in GNOME (which is what you're running on Debian), there might well be something in the documentation, or you could look at the keyboard and shortcut settings.

Comment: @StephenKitt Is there anything corresponding for the action *Show desktop* in Debian?

Comment: In the keyboard settings, in "Navigation", "Hide all normal windows" should do the trick; it doesn't have a default shortcut, you'll need to assign one yourself (click on it and press the keys you wish to use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot show hovering view of keybindings in Gnome 3.14.

Stephen's answers in comments

- No hovering help menu in Debian, like in Ubuntu (Unity).
- *Keyboard > Shortcuts > Navigation > Hide all normal windows* where I set the keybinding <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to show/hide desktop.

To have Desktop icons in Desktop

- *Tweak tool > Desktop > Icons on Desktop On*

It would be really nice to find a one-liner for this task. TODO